# 6A82 APDU communication issue between NFC enabled Android phone and ISO/IEC 14443-4 Smart Card

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu

I'm currently working with an Android payment application using NFC.For this purpose Android application need to send and receive APDU commands to  ISO/IEC 14443-4 Smart Card.

When i test my application using Galaxy S5(OS 4.4.2) , or Galaxy s3(OS 4.1.2) I'm getting `6A82`

My Code flow is going like below:

1st step ->

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
 IsoDep iso = IsoDep.get(tag); 
 iso.connect();
```

2nd step ->
By using `iso.transceive()..`
I'm sending APDU command  `0084000008` from Mobile Application to Smard Card and
receiving `F5BC9C9F3A2B7C179000` as response.

3rd Step ->
using `iso.isConnect()` I'm checking the connection and
-> Connection available

4th Step ->
By using `iso.transceive()..`
sending APDU command : `903203000A1403CF549C2B7520389C`
receiving : `6A82`  All the time

I would be happy if anyone suggest me why I'm getting strange File not found (`6A82`) for this APDU command.

Comment: What smartcard are you using? What application is running on the card? What's the protocol specification of that card/application?

Comment: Smartcard - gemalto,
Protocol Specification - CEPAS, Application running on the card - ezlink specific

Answer (score 0):

after calling `iso.connect()` you should send select apdu first
00A40400 + 
for example :

(u should convert hex to bytes first)

```
aid = AABBCCDD;

byte[] selectCmd = 00A4040004AABBCCDD

isoDep.transceive(command)
```